# Interpreting variogram: negative values beyond model sill?

Tags: autocorrelation, variogram

The negative values mean that there is negative autocorrelation at some far distance, like a repulsion.  How would this affect assessment of the range?

(This is just for learning the scale of a spatial process, not for kriging.)